# Phonegap 3 application won't enter deviceready()

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I've recently managed to upgrade my version of Phonegap from 2.9 to 3.3 and have only just now managed to upgrade my project to work in 3.3

I am now getting an error where my application will not enter the deviceready() state. Prior to changing to +3.0, my application entered deviceready() just fine... I have run the CLI 'build' and'update' commands to modify my project to the +3.0 specifications and moved things around on my own so certain errors regarding plug-ins would be resolved.

I should also mention that I've added this part only recently and it seems to have addressed an NPObject error (saw it in the helloworld app generated by phonegap, figured I should add it):

```
<script src="js/index.js">app.initialize()</script>
```

Here is the relevant chunk of html code where deviceready should be called:

Within index.html:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="cordova/lib/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js">app.initialize()</script>
<script src="js/mustache.js"></script>
<script>
.
.
.
    function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        //db = window.openDatabase("Notes","1.0","Saved Notes", 200000);
        //db.transaction(getDBNotes, onDBError, onDBSuccess);
        console.log("WITHIN onDeviceReady()");
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, onFSError);
    }
```

And here is my index.js file, in case this is important at all:

```
            var app = {
        // Application Constructor
        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        // Bind Event Listeners
        //
        // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
        // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        },
        // deviceready Event Handler
        //
        // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
        // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
        onDeviceReady: function() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
            console.log("within index.js- app.onDeviceReady()");
        },
        // Update DOM on a Received Event
        receivedEvent: function(id) {
            var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
            var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
            var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

            listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

            console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        }
    };
```

When I run my app within eclipse on my device I get this error:

```
"deviceready has not fired after 5 second.", source: file://android_asset/www/cordova.lib/cordova.js
```

I have been racking my brain trying to get this project up and running so I can continue development but I can't seem to resolve this issue.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: place this code on top list <script src="cordova/lib/cordova.js"></script>, because cordova.js file should be declared on top of all js files.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. That shouldn't matter as the only scripts running before cordova.js are jquery and jquery mobile script libraries which are unrelated to the deviceready issue.

Comment: I seemed to have fixed the issue by moving the cordova_plugins.js file back to the root of android_assets/www/ and simply adding a reference to the plugin in my index.html

Comment: Oh, I also changed the reference to my cordova.js file from cordova/lib/ to a cordova.js file found in the root... I think maybe I was referencing the 2.9 cordova.js file instead of the newly built 3.3 js file.

Comment: yes ur above issue was not finding cordova.js file so it was not able to enter deviceready(). so next time be careful with the cordova.js version and references

Comment: I'm having similar issues, but only when the device is offline. If the device is connected to the internet, everything seems to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: @ThilakRao are you importing your scripts from a URL instead of locally? I don't know if phonegap scripts are offered through URL but I know jQuery and jQuery mobile scripts are, among many others... It might be the case that they won't load if not connected... Try and get local copies if you are currently importing from URLs

Comment: Everything is locally being served.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, I kept seeing this in my log in Eclipse.

> "E/Web Console(7662): Uncaught module
>   org.apache.cordova.plugin.canvas.canvas already defined:79"

Figured out that if I removed this from "platforms/android/.staging/www/cordova_plugins.js", it seems to have fixed my issue as it was throwing itself out of the Cordova.js because it's an exception.

```
 03-12 17:21:10.411: E/Web Console(7662): Uncaught module
 org.apache.cordova.plugin.canvas.canvas already defined:79
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding the following to config.xml will work. for the same reason as I outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693760/ios-deviceready-has-not-fired-after-5-seconds/23313029#23313029)

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Cordova 3 changed how the cordova/phonegap script is referred to, try changing this:

```
<script src="cordova/lib/cordova.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```